# How do I combine two JQuery functions

Tags: jquery

Could someone please give me a hand and tell me what is wrong with this script? The answer that was posted did not work. What I get when I use that code is the entire html page being submitted. This is what I can see from the console. Can someone please help me out? Thanks.

---

```
$(function() {
    $('#add_customer_form').submit(function() {
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        var url = $(this).attr('action');
        var method = $(this).attr('method');
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: method,
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var $div = $('<div>').attr('id', 'message').html(data.message);
                if(data.success == 0) {
                    $div.addClass('error');
                } else {
                    // START CHANGE
                    // you need to get `datastring` from somewhere
                    $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "body.php?action=admCustomer",
                       data: dataString,
                       success: function(){
                           $('#contact input[type=text]').val('');
                           $div.addClass('success');
                       }
                    });
                    // END CHANGE
                }
                $('body').append($div);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: It’s quite hard to understand your question...

Comment: Are you trying to send the information? The add_customer_form data is already being sent. You are trying to send it twice....

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps changing

```
var $div = $('<div>').attr('id', 'message').html(data.message);
```

to

```
var $div = $('<div/>').attr('id', 'message').html(data.message);
```

would do the trick?

Comment: Hi snz3.. Actually, I reposted the problem and Paolo helped me to get it working. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('#add_customer_form').submit(function() {
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        var url = $(this).attr('action');
        var method = $(this).attr('method');
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: method,
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var $div = $('<div>').attr('id', 'message').html(data.message);
                if(data.success == 0) {
                    $div.addClass('error');
                } else {
                    // START CHANGE
                    // you need to get `datastring` from somewhere
                    $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "body.php?action=admCustomer",
                       data: dataString,
                       success: function(){
                           $('#contact input[type=text]').val('');
                           $div.addClass('success');
                       }
                    });
                    // END CHANGE
                }
                $('body').append($div);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Piskvor. Thanks for the help! Where you have your comment:
"// you need to get `datastring` from somewhere"

My datastring is actually above the starting $(function(). Is this ok or does the datastring var need to be inside the else block where your comment is?

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Hmm, in that case it's most probably in the global scope and should be available inside your function.